# Something Easier than jq UI Dialog?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-2, modal-dialog

Is it just me, or is Jquery UI Dialog really difficult to grasp.  I am not a javascript developer, and I don't feel like learning the language (not right now anyway... this project is on a deadline!).  Isn't there anything simpler that uses the latest jquery and is relatively simple to use?  Like you know, set an id or a class (id preferably) for the form and call a simple jquery function?  Why does it have to be so hard?  And no simpleDialog.  Some of those scripts conflict with my other scripts and make my other jquery function crap out (I spent 13 hours yesterday trying to figure that one out)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not clear what you mean for "simpler" ;) anyway you can give a try to:

http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal/

and here you have a list with 15 alternatives...

http://choosedaily.com/1178/15-jquery-popup-modal-dialog-plugins-tutorials/

Answer (score 1):

I've never used the UI Dialog, but you can try a modal popup: http://www.queness.com/post/77/simple-jquery-modal-window-tutorial

You can style it however you like, and use simple jquery show/hide functions to display it. =)